# QGIS WMS layer to GeoTIFF

Tags: qgis, wms, geotiff-tiff

I'm trying to export a WMS layer in QGIS 3.28 to Geotiff format. The resulting GeoTIFF file is blank white with no data.

VRT is disabled and extent is correct. Issue occurs for both output mode raw data and rendered image.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: How are you trying to export it, what is your workflow?

Comment: Does the WMS not have TIFF as an output format?

Answer (score 1):

You can export WMS/WMTS to TIF with georeferencing (world file) from print layout.

Create a new print layout. Project -> New print layout. Add a map to the sheet, and export to georeferenced tif (world file).

[image]

P.S. For the **WMTS** layer you can set the desired zoom for export.

[image]

Comment: A WMS doesn't have zoom levels.  Your example is a WMTS

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've corrected the answer.